# Firebase transaction precision loss

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, precision

In Firebase real time database i have a path like this ../funds/balance with a value of 10.

I have a function doing a transaction which decrease the balance by 2 cents.

The first time i remove 2 cents everything works and balance is saved has 9.98.

I do it one more time everything console log show i read 9.98 from the db and after data is updated firebase console show 9.96.

Next time i do it remember that Firebase console shows 9.96 but when i console log the value received in the transaction is currently 9.96000001.

Someone nows why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known property of floating-point representations.

The issue arises because, in this case, because 0.02 cannot be represented exactly as a floating-point number. It can be represented exactly in *decimal* (2x10^-1), but in *binary* it has a recurring "1001" (1.1001100110011001... x2^-3).

What you are seeing is analogous to representing 1/3 in decimal as 0.333. You expect that subtracting 1/3 from one 3 times would leave 0, but subtracting 0.333 from one 3 times leaves 0.001.

The solution is not to represent money as floating-point. In SQL you'd use a `MONEY`, `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` type or, more generally, you can represent money as an integer number of pennies (or hundreths of a penny, etc., according to your needs).

There's an article called *"What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"* that you can find online that explains the issue.

Comment: Yes i know but the Firebase console show that it stored 9.96, it should then show 9.960000000001. not 9.96.

Comment: Ok thanks i got it, In fact i read something that was not totally exact on the best way to handle currency and since i didn't need to deal with this side of javascript that much i wasn't figuring that it's the 9.96 * 100 that was giving 9.96000000001 something like this.  The value coming from the DB was indeed ok, it was 9.96.